# How to rotate MapView while keeping labels and marker (overlays) unrotated?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing a `MapActivity` which shows route from current location to a `GeoPoint`.

`MapView` has to be compass-enabled; It should rotate depending on the direction user is facing. I am able to rotate `MapView` using `RotateView` as mentioned in `MapsDemo` example.

```
android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-8/samples/MapsDemo
```

Here the problem is the whole `MapView` is rotated, resulting in labels and markers getting rotated.

Is there any way to achieve `MapView` rotation with proper readable labels and markers?

I have to support Android version 2.2 so cannot use `MapView.rotate()` even if it could have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Once the device orientation is changed, the entire mapview and markers and labels are redrawn..don't think its possible..

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, On Oreintation Change the entire mapview is redrawn and an exception pops up, I faced the same problem, and had to fix the orientation.